# Javascript onmouseover and onmouseout when creating <img> programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onmouseover

I've found explanations on Stack Exchange on how to do this for an already existing image tag, like this:

```
<img src="./img/action_contact.png" onmouseover="this.src='./img/action_contact_hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='./img/action_contact.png'">
```

but if I'm programmatically creating it as below, I can't figure out how to use single and double quotations properly to get the code to compile and function.

```
$('<img src="./img/action_contact.png" onmouseover="this.src="./img/action_contact_hover.png";" onmouseout="./img/action_contact.png";">')appendTo('#action' + i);
```

Comment: Consider using jQuery to add your event handlers rather than putting it in your HTML. See [the `on` method at jQuery.com](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use escaped single quotes around the JS strings in the attributes (i.e. `\'`). You are also missing the `.` before `appendTo`.

```
$('<img src="./img/action_contact.png" onmouseover="this.src=\'hover.jpg\';" onmouseout="this.src=\'original.jpg\';">').appendTo('#action' + i);
```

However, a more-readable way to do this would be to use jQuery's [`attr`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) method.

```
$('<img src="./img/action_contact.png">')
    .attr('onmouseover', 'this.src="hover.jpg";')
    .attr('onmouseout', 'this.src="original.jpg";')
    .appendTo('#action' + i);
```

You can even get really dynamic, and use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) and data attributes, to completely separate content and functionality, and get rid of the ugly event attributes.

```js
//Create an example image.
var i = 1;//for example
$('<img class="swap" />')
    .attr('src', 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-icon.png')
    .attr('data-hoverover', 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/se/se-icon.png')
    .attr('data-hoverout', 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-icon.png')
    .appendTo('#action' + i);

//Handle swapping.
$(document)
    .on('mouseenter', 'img.swap', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.attr('src', $this.attr('data-hoverover'));
    })
    .on('mouseleave', 'img.swap', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.attr('src', $this.attr('data-hoverout'));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="action1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to escape some of the ticks using `\`.

```
$('<img src="./img/action_contact.png" onmouseover="this.src=\'hover.jpg\';" onmouseout="this.src=\'original.jpg\';">')appendTo('#action' + i);
```